# How to get Radare2 to use symbol table information for library calls?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, glibc, disassembly

Objdump can figure out when the binary is calling GLIBC functions, like `printf`:

```
 $ objdump -d crackme03.64 -Mintel | grep printf
 5c8:   ff 25 12 0a 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200a12]    #200fe0 <__printf_chk@GLIBC_2.3.4>
```

However, looking at the same address, Radare is much less helpful:

```
[0x000005c8]> pd 2
/ (fcn) sub.__cxa_finalize_224_5c8 8
|   sub.__cxa_finalize_224_5c8 ();
|           ; CALL XREF from 0x000007bc (sym.main)
|           ; CALL XREF from 0x00000809 (sym.main)
|           0x000005c8      ff25120a2000   jmp qword [reloc.__cxa_finalize_224] ; [0x200fe0:8]=0 LEA reloc.__cxa_finalize_224 ; reloc.__cxa_finalize_224
\           0x000005ce      6690           nop
```

Is there a way to ask Radare to figure out what these functions correspond to?

Comment: Objdump is using the same symbol-table information that dynamic linking uses at run-time to fill in the GOT values.  Is that what you want Radare2 to do?  If so, a better title might be "... to use symbol table information for library calls".  You're only analyzing a *call to* a glibc function, not the code of the glibc function.  (The latter can be tricky because of lazy dynamic linking, and runtime dispatching for functions like `memset`.)

Comment: Changed, thank you for clarifying

Comment: This question should be on reverseengineering.stackexchange.com You should flag it to get it migrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you're using the newest version from git.

Radare2’s development is pretty quick – the project evolves every day, therefore it’s recommended to use the current git version. Update your version and it should solve your problem:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/radare/radare2.git
$ cd radare2
$ ./sys/install.sh
```

Comment: Yep, got the same answer in IRC and it is unfortunately correct. Would be really cool if there were packages for Linux distros (e.g. a PPA, RPMs for download, etc).